# Wait for user input within timed nested loops

Tags: python, loops, nested, pygame, user-input

I want to program a Stop Signal Response Task.  I have 90% of it in the bag, but I'm having really issues with dealing with keyboard events within nested loops...I have tried pygame...But it either does not record a response or hangs in the loop.

This loop represents one trial which consists of an object being presented on the screen for a total of 1.25 seconds (ether a square or circle).

If it's a square, a participant has to press "z", if it's a circle, they have to press "/"...
It loops through array indexes that contain which object will appear on screen, and whether there will be a beep or not (`beeplist[i]`)

On some trials, there will be a beep at a variable time (SSD... Stop Signal Delay is defined outside this loop which then changes with performance).
If there is a beep, the person is expected to not respond. (I don't want it to wait for a response though)

So...I want to record the response of the person (which button they press), and reaction time.
I want first response to be recorded only.

Please could anyone help me figure out how I'd take the response from the keyboard and reaction time please?

Here's what I got:

```
presses = None
starttime = time.time()
trial_ST.append(starttime)
end_time = time.time() + 1.250 #makes sure each trial is only 0.5s in total
StopSignalTime = starttime + SSD # generates the time at which the SS is to be presented (if it is)
while time.time() < SSD:
    presses = ####### Need this to wait for specific keypress (either z or /)
    response.append(presses) #write the response to an array
if beeplist[i] == 1:
    tone.play()
while time.time() < end_time:
    if presses is None:
        presses = ####### Need this to wait for specific keypress (either z or /)
        response.append(presses) #write the response to an array
SSDlist = SSDlist.append(SSD)
if beeplist[i] == 1:
    if presses == None:
        SSD = SSD + 0.05
    else:
        SSD = SSD = 0.05
print "end of block iteration"
blockiteration = blockiteration + 1
startTask = False
restblock()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to exit the loop if you detect the press, but I can't this exit condition in your while loop :-)

Also if you detect the "right" press you can take the time with time.time() and substract the the starttime to get the actual time difference

```
time_diff = time.time() - starttime
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for your suggestion... I can't get how to break out of the loop if no key is detected... I don't want it to hang around for a response... should have mentioned that.

Comment: I would combine the two loops and use the following condition:
"while time.time() < end_time".
In the loop you can use a "break" statement, where you can exit the loop as soon as you have the desired key. If no key is pressed, the loop exits when time.time() is past end_time.
"time.time() < SSD" won't work, as SSD is a time span (as far as I understand from your code) and time.time() is the actual time which is a much higher value. So your loop condition is never fulfilled. Your program wouldn't enter the first loop at all.

Comment: ooooooooooh... Gotcha! I'll try combine these mofo's and get back to you.  Thanks again Lukas (spelled your name right this time)